# jquery validate amount of errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate 1.11.1 and jQuery 1.11.3.

I'm building some kind of survey website with multiple input and form elements.

```
    $(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'alert alert-danger',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.closest('.panel'));
        }
    });

    $("#screenForm").validate({
        debug: true,
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
                options: {
                    required: true
                },
                options2: {
                    required: true
                },
                checkbox1: {
                    required: true
                },
                checkbox1other: {
                    required: {       
                        depends: function(element) {
                            console.log($("#checkboxOther:checked").length == 1);
                            return $("#checkboxOther:checked").length == 1;
                        }
                    }
                },
                a_SQhyu5q__3__491: {
                    required: true
                },
                a_SQk8wb8__3__491: {
                    required: true
                }
        },
        groups: {
            matrix: "a_SQhyu5q__3__491 a_SQk8wb8__3__491"
        },
        messages: {
            checkbox1other: "Please fill in details"
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.remove();
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.panel').removeClass('<%=panelColor%>');
            $(element).closest('.panel').addClass('panel-danger');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.panel').removeClass('panel-danger');
            $(element).closest('.panel').addClass('<%=panelColor%>');
        }
    });
});
```

The `a_SQhyu5q__3__491` and `a_SQk8wb8__3__491` are displayed in the same panel. When both are not filled in I get two error messages displaying that these fields are required. Since they are in the same panel I would like to display only one error message when that happens and not two.

I need some sort of limit on the amount of "required errors" so this never goes over one.

I have tried the groups option, but when one of the two inputs is filled in the error message isn't displayed for the second one which should also be filled in.

For options, `options2` and `checkbox1` all still have their own message which should not be combined with the other ones. It's just that for the `a_SQhyu5q__3__491` and `a_SQk8wb8__3__491` the error message should be combined.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that the group option is working for me. Some external problems or problems with jQuery Validate, (not sure) made it look like it wasn't working. When I checked manualy with the .valid() function the error message immediatly showed up.